# Difference between Window Task CPU Utilization and Oshi CPU usage

Tags: java, oshi

I using Oshi API (https://github.com/oshi/oshi) to get the CPU usage. However, why the value is different from Task Manager CPU Utilization? What is my mistake?

*My Program - Average 11.13%*

[image]

*Task Manager - Average around 29%*

[image]

*Edited Code*

```
private SystemInfo systemInformation = new SystemInfo();
private CentralProcessor proc = systemInformation.getHardware().getProcessor();

private static float[] floatArrayPercent(double d) {
  float[] f = new float[1];
  f[0] = (float) (100d * d);
  return f;
}

private double cpuData(CentralProcessor proc) {
  double d = proc.getSystemCpuLoadBetweenTicks(oldTicks);
  oldTicks = proc.getSystemCpuLoadTicks();
  return d;
}


@Scheduled(fixedRate = 10)
public void processProcessorInformation() {
  System.out.println("The percentage of the floating value  cpu: " + floatArrayPercent(cpuData(proc))[0]);
}
```

Comment: At a guess? Assumed you only have [one processor](http://oshi.github.io/oshi/apidocs/oshi/hardware/CentralProcessor.html#getPhysicalProcessorCount()) (you probably have multiple). I mean [one processor](http://oshi.github.io/oshi/apidocs/oshi/hardware/CentralProcessor.html#getLogicalProcessorCount()). It's complicated on modern CPUs. Because they usually mean "one core". But they can also mean two-hyperthreads per core. Humble brag: my 8 year old desktop has 24 cpus. Two physical. Six cores each. Each core with hyperthreads.

Comment: Of course, a brand new [AMD thread ripper 3990x](https://www.theverge.com/2020/1/6/21054050/amd-64-core-processor-threadripper-3990x-release-date-pricing-ces-2020) would say 128 cpus with one physical cpu.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch good guess but the error is in the opposite direction (Windows shows lower % than one would assume based on raw calculations).  The answer happens to be cumulative vs. instantaneous...

Comment: @DanielWiddis I generally use Mac or Linux. Not exclusively. But generally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that while you intended to do a "recent" usage calculation, you have a stray line of code resetting it to a cumulative (since startup) usage calculation.

The `getSystemCpuLoadBetweenTicks(oldTicks)` calculation measures the elapsed user, system, idle, etc. ticks from the current counters to the previous ones you passed to it and will give you usage between those timeslices.  In your `cpuData()` method you correctly save the old ticks and probably intend to use them again. That part's correct.

However, in your `processProcessorInformation()` you zero out the `oldTicks` array each time:  `oldTicks = new long[TickType.values().length];`.  And thus the value being returned is the cumulative average CPU usage since you started, rather than the last 10 seconds.   Deleting that line (or moving it outside the scheduled method) should give you the results you expect.

You also don't need a fresh copy of the `cpu` object each time.  You can move that initialization out of the scheduled method while you're moving the `oldTicks` initialization.

On a related note, @Elliot-Frisch mentioned in the comments about calculations involving multiple processors.  This is a useful warning when comparing processor ticks vs. time (e.g., if you're measuring ticks between elapsed time periods).  Ticks accumulate on every logical processor, so you would need to make sure you scale the "elapsed time" to include every logical processor as well.   This applies when dealing with per-Process CPU calculations, as you only have process up time available as a denominator, and in this case Windows Task Manager is scaled to ensure no process exceeds 100%, while *nix results (on `top`) are not scaled and it's possible to exceed 100%.

However, for System CPU usage, we have an "idle" tick counter available, which does accumulate ticks on all the processors and is a better choice for calculating percent usage -- and is what's used in the `getSystemCpuLoadBetweenTicks()` method, so this correction is not required.

Comment: Thank you so much. I still have some questions in using oshi.
        
1) I already edited the code above : remove zero out the oldTicks and cpu object. Am i correct? 

2) If i put the fixed rate of the scheduler for the processProcessorInformation() method to 5 minutes, will it affect the result? 

2) What is the difference between processor.getSystemLoadAverage(3) and processor.getSystemCpuLoadBetweenTicks(oldTicks) ? Based on the javadoc,the load average may be unavailable on some platforms (e.g., Windows) where it is expensive to implement this method. Is it no available for Window 7

Comment: 1) Sounds right.  2) If you make it 5 minutes, that's the average CPU usage you'll get, the average of the last 5 minutes.  It likely won't match Task Manager, which looks like it averages every few seconds.  3) the Load Average is defined in *nix as an exponential moving average of system CPU usage over the last 1, 5, and 15 minutes respectively.  If you multiplied your 5-minute-average CPU usage calculation by the number of logical processors you'd get a number similar to the second element (but not exact because exponential moving average is different than simple moving average).